# How do I set up Code Igniter if my public html folder is a soft link?

Tags: codeigniter, symlink

I am setting up Code Igniter. My public html folder is a soft link to another folder on my server.

Hence, my directory structure looks like

```
README       errors.txt  license.txt     system
application  html   user_guide
```

where html is a soft link to another folder `/var/www/myPublicHTML/`. html contains my index.php file.

Code Igniter currently issues this error.

```
Your system folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: index.php
```

However, I did specify this in my index.php file within the html soft link / folder.

```
$system_path = '../system';
$application_folder = '../application';
```

Why is this error still surfacing? I feel that it may be a soft link issue. Thank you.

Comment: Why do you change default configuration in index.php ? leave it default and try

Comment: I don't want my application and system folders in my public html folder. These are php scripts.

Comment: The directory structure you pasted above, what is the path to that folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The directory that the system symlink points to should permit access to all users. The webserver is probably attempting to access the `system` directory but doesn't have the proper clearance to do so (Note that the webserver doesn't use your user credentials to do its work).

If the `system` symlink points to `/var/www/frameworks/CodeIgniter/2.x.x/system` you should see to it that `/var/www/frameworks/CodeIgniter/2.x.x/system` is accessible to all users in order to allow the webserver to access that directory as well.

Running `chmod 755 -R /var/www/frameworks/CodeIgniter/2.x.x/system` should grant read and execute access to ALL users (and full access to yourself). Needless to say that you should enter the path to your system directory in the above command ;).

Comment: Thanks, it was a permissions issue.

Answer (score 0):

It should be work by default. if not write full path

```
$system_path = '/var/www/myPublicHTML/system';
$application_folder = '/var/www/myPublicHTML/application';
```

Comment: Thanks, but this oddly doesn't work either. The same error is being issued.

Answer (score 0):

hi i got the similar problem after a little research i got to know that as i have installed xampp in different folder under c drive which is xampp1 thats why it was getting error so i supplied full path in config.php file which is

$system_path = 'C:/xampp1/htdocs/project/application/system';